# how to search through all documents for a specific field value

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how to search through all documents for a specific field value

for eg: if i want the field: blood_group 'A+' from all documents and show me all documents which has 'A+' in it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IhT9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tkEG.png

[source code](https://github.com/swojas/plasma-donation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [.where](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/where.html) filter on the collection reference's query like below:

```dart
final QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('blood_group', isEqualTo: 'A+').get();   
final List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> documentSnapshotList = querySnapshot.docs;

for (QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot in documentSnapshotList) {
    print(snapshot.data());
}
```

Comment: This will not work in the current structure as posted. It has to be await for, because it's a Future \ async request.

Comment: I just added the missing `await` to the solution. Could you post the part of the project's code relevant to the question? It'll help make this easier.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele how do i take for eg blood_group and show it on a new screen

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you want this to be used? It's difficult going through your entire project for this.

Comment: @VictorEronmosele sure i want it in my main https://github.com/swojas/plasma-donation/blob/master/lib/main.dart at very last elevatedbutton

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.where` option. Based on your firebase structure in the picture, you can use the following code, to get a list of all documents that satisfy your request.

```
Future<QuerySnapshot> bloodgroup (String bloodGroup) async {
 return await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Donation').where('blood_group', isEqualTo: bloodGroup).get();
}


void getDocs() async {
QuerySnapshot allResults = await bloodgroup('A+');

for (var item in allResults){
print(item.id); //this will print the id of all the documents which are A+.
 }
}
```